# Chosen multi-select box value goes NULL in callback

Tags: javascript, jquery

So, here's an odd thing.  I have a "Chosen" multiple select box that has values.  I've put console log statements all throughout the code and my value is being returned in all of them, but when I put a breakpoint in the JAVA method that accepts the callback and returns data - the value comes in NULL.  Here's some sample code.

```
$("#dropdownBox").chosen({});
$("#dropdownBox").change(function() {
$('#dropdownBox').trigger("chosen:updated");
 var tText = $("#dropdownBox").val();
console.log("TText is " + tText);
```

This returns the value selected in the console - and returns a list when multiple items are chosen
    });

later in the file in a separate method

```
var type = $("#dropdownBox").val();
    console.log("type on the call is = " + type);
 //This returns the same value as before
    $.request({
        url : 'urlToGetData',
        callback : loadJournalListCallback,
        callbackError : function(data) {
            $('#search-button, #clear-button').enable();
            $('#modal-srch-button, #modal-clr-button').enable();
            showErr(data, 4000);
        },
        data : {
            siteId : siteId,
            tType : type
        }
    });
```

Comment: Where is the part where its coming in NULL?

Comment: That's in the Java code - somewhere between the callback and the web service, the variable is being dropped.

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @TaterTut Then include the Java. You're asking us to debug an error in a particular snippet of code, and then excluding it from your question. I'm not sure how you expect us to debug the part that *isn't* working, by only supplying us with the part that *is* working.

Comment: Because the Java is moot - it's picking up everything else just fine, and truthfully, at the point I'm setting my breakpoint and seeing the NULL - it's simply reading the HTTP header.  That's it.  But if it helps - 

String transactionType = this.getHttpParameter("tType");